# How to get Product name in phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I want to get Product name in Phtml file and i checked this three collection but in that there are no product name available.

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productPrice = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productimageCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to load product to get product name

**With Object Manager**

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

Note: Don't use objectManager directly

**With Factory Method**

```
<?php

  protected $product;  

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->product->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

Then call `getProduct` function in your phtml file

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id
$product=$this->getProduct($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productID); 
 $product->getName()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code in phtml.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setPageSize(3) //Selecting 3 products
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}
```

Comment: this method not working for product collection..

Answer (score 1):

Use Factory and inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` product factory in your file.That is best coding standard.

```
protected $product;  

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->product->create()->load($id);
    }

}

$productId = "1256"; //Your Product Id
$product=$this->getProduct($productId);

echo $product->getName();
```