# display product name through product id in custom tab in magento2

Tags: magento2

hello everyone I want to display the product name through product id which is stored in the database through that I want to display the product name in the custom tab in admin grid 
screenshot is below
[image]

Comment: This might help you - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179235/how-to-get-product-name-in-phtml-file-in-magento2

Comment: I want to use in block file ex: abc\B\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab

Comment: you must be getting product id as you mentioned its stored already . you simply needs to fetch product name from it the above mentioned link gives you the idea about it. how you are displaying name ,width and other fields? can you please provide some code?

Comment: $fieldset->addField(
            'name',
            'text',
            [
                'name'        => 'name',
                'label'    => __('name'),
                'required'     => true
            ]
        ); like this all things are coming it is in block file